# Javascript Flow generic functions syntax

Tags: javascript, generics, flowtype

I'm facing some syntax errors when trying to write generic map function.

```
function mymap<A, B>(fun: (_: A) => B, array: Array<A>): Array<B> {
    let result: Array<B> = [];
    for (let i of array)
        result.push(fun(i));
    return result;
}

let x = mymap<number, number>(x => x, [1, 2, 3]);
                            ^ Unexpected token
```

Flow says: `Unexpected token >`. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: On which of the seven `>`s?

Comment: after second `number` type declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow is a type checker only. While it doesn't allow type overloading of generic implementation, you shouldn't specify types while you call a function. Flow will just try to check arguments for compatibility with the signature of the function and deduct the output type. So you just need to write

```
let x = mymap(x => x, [1, 2, 3]);
```

and Flow will deduct the output type of the expression and apply it to the `x` variable.

Or you can explicitly specify a type of `x`:

```
let x: Array<number> = mymap(x => x, [1, 2, 3]);
```

In this case Flow can compare a deducted type with the required type, and if you erroneously will use an incorrect mapping function like `x => x.toString()`, then Flow will warn you about that:

```
   let x: Array<number> = mymap(x => x.toString(), [1, 2, 3]);
//              ^ string             ^ This type is incompatible with number
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. So there is no way to limit function calls to homogenic lists only? I.e. this showing an error: `mymap(x => x, [1, 'b', 3])`

Comment: It seems that Flow can't do this. By the way, in TypeScript your initial version with `mymap<number, number>(...)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

At some point Flow [added support for generics](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/)

```
function mymap<A, B>(func: <A, B>(param: A) => B, array: Array<A>): Array<B> {
    let result: Array<B> = [];
    for (let i of array)
        result.push(fun(i));
    return result;
}
```